# WCF Service User Identification

Tags: iis-7, windows-server-2008, .net-4.5, wcf-security, kerberos

I am creating a .NET 4.5 WCF web service for deployment on Windows Server 2008 running IIS 7.0.  I want my web service to identify the users who access the service by authenticating a Kerberos token string that is passed through the web service.  I can't use Integrated Windows Authentication (some of my clients are using Linux machines) so, I must pass the token string.  Does anyone know how I can do the following:

1. Generate a Kerberos token string in C# .NET 4.5 based a users current identity.
2. Validate a Kerberos token string in C# .NET 4.5 and get the associate username.

Thanks!

Comment: @RichardEv Sorry for not responding sooner.  I haven't found a way to do what I had described in my question.  From what I've researched, I think that Fredrik's answer is as good as it's going to get...create two bindings for the same service...one with integrated Windows authentication and one without (and pass the user's username and password).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could maybe expose the service with two bindings, one for Windows-users with Windows-authentication and one for others using user name authentication. Is it an intranet or internet scanario? How are the Linux users identified?

Comment: Sorry for not accepting your answer sooner.  Thanks for your help!